# Check process on Remote Computer before initiating

Tags: c#

I have to check a process on remote computer. If it is running do not start otherwise start process on remote computer but issue is that the process is not visible to all users so whenever I use below syntax, it throws an exception: `Cannot connect to remote machine`.

```
Process [] ipByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad", "169.0.0.0");
```

How do I pass username and password to check if the process is running?

Comment: Do you have a machine on your network with the IP address 169.0.0.0?

Comment: its different ip. i just wanted to show example thats why I used 169.0.0.0. I just want to know how to pass credentials while checking process because process is seen to some authorized accounts on network?

Answer (score 0):

You could try impersonating.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx

```
public class Test {

 [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern bool LogonUser(string principal, string authority, string password, LogonSessionType logonType, LogonProvider logonProvider, out IntPtr token);

 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
 static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

 enum LogonSessionType : uint {
  Interactive = 2,
  Network,
  Batch,
  Service,
  NetworkCleartext = 8,
  NewCredentials
 }

 enum LogonProvider : uint {
  Default = 0,
  WinNT35,
  WinNT40, //NTLM
  WinNT50  //Kerb or NTLM
 }

 void DoTest() {
  IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
  WindowsImpersonationContext user = null;
  try {  
   bool loggedin = LogonUser("username", "authority", "password", LogonSessionType.Interactive, LogonProvider.Default, out token);
   if (loggedin) {
    WindowsIdentity id = new WindowsIdentity(token);
    user = id.Impersonate();

    Process [] ipByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad", "169.0.0.0");
   }
  } catch (Exception ex) {

  } finally {
   if (user != null) {
    user.Undo();
   }
   if (token != IntPtr.Zero) {
    CloseHandle(token);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And if that does not work, you could try WMI

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_process_controller.aspx